# Google App Engine Firefox and IE missing HTTP Referer header

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

When making a HTTP request to a Cloud Endpoints API running on App Engine (standard), the server errors. Stackdriver logs showed:

```
InvalidResponseError: status must be a str, got 'unicode' (u'403 Requests from referer <empty> are blocked.')"
```

I'm using an auto-generated, Angular2, Typescript client, generated using [Swagger's online editor](http://editor.swagger.io/). The generated code uses the following Angular2 modules when making the request:

```
import { Http, Headers, URLSearchParams }                    from '@angular/http';
import { RequestMethod, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { Response, ResponseContentType }                     from '@angular/http';
```

Everything works in Chrome, but not in Firefox and IE. As an experiment, I removed any headers just before the Angular2 client made the HTTP request (`headers:undefined`)

```
let requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            headers: undefined,
            body: body == null ? '' : JSON.stringify(body),
            search: queryParameters
});

this.http.request(path, requestOptions);
```

This fixed the issue and Firefox and IE worked. Before setting `headers` to `undefined`, the **only** header being added was:

```
headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

Looking at the HTTP headers from Chrome and Firefox, Firefox is missing `Referer`

Firefox Request Headers (missing `Referer`)

```
Host: api.endpoints.myapp.appspot.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

Chrome Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Connection:keep-alive
Host:api.endpoints.myapp.appspot.com
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/editor
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Since the Google App Engine API restricts access using an API Key and a HTTP referrer whitelist:

- http://localhost/*
- http://staging.myserver.com/*

...the empty referrer causes the HTTP request to be rejected. Questions:

- Why would removing the entire header in the angular 2 client, result in the referer being populated?
- If empty an empty referer is rejected by Google App Engine when restricting API Key access, how should I secure my API by client (i.e. not user authentication).

Comment: If I understand this correctly, the client's browser using Angular issues HTTP requests to your Cloud Endpoints.  The endpoints with a given API key use the [Referer header](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-5.5.2) to accept requests providing a given API key.  The referer header is set by the client browser at request time and [cannot be modified by client code](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name) when issuing the request (assuming most mainstream compliant browsers).  I could not get any browser to omit the `Referer` header by using `XMLHttpRequest.setHeader()`.

Comment: Can you successfully get any browser to omit the `Referer` header using [`XMLHttpRequest.setHeader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)?  If so, which browser-versions and which headers?  Note that there are situations in which the `Referer` header [will be omitted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer)